# Sort Extracted Data Based On Image Region

Tags: r, image-processing, feature-extraction, r-raster

I have analysed tree core images through the `raster` package in an attempt to perform image analysis. In the image:

http://dx.doi.org/10.6084/m9.figshare.1555854

You can see the measured "vessels" (black and numbered) and also annual lines (red) which have been drawn using the `locator` function and represent each year of growth of the tree core.

By generating a list of the maximum y coordinates of each annual line I have been able to sort the vessels into years for this image. Which is what I am looking for. However, it has occurred to me that in reality things can get a little more difficult as seen in the next image:

http://figshare.com/articles/Complicated/1555855

The approach above will not work on this image as vessels from each year overrun so using the maximum y coordinates will not return the correct result.

So can anyone suggest another approach which may overcome this limitation? I have thought about using `spatialpolygons` but not sure this will achieve what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the lines by clicking on the plot, you can use raster function `drawLine` or, for polygons, `drawPoly`. You could rasterize the polygons and mask that with the original image to get the vessels grouped by polygon (year).